# DbScanExpression with join and left table select

Tags: entity-framework, join, where-clause, interceptor

colleagues.

I have a group of classes(tables) which have some common properties(columns). What I would like to do is using EntityFramework intercept select queries and modify them.

I would like to add join and some where clauses. But don't know how to project left table without explicit properties selection.

Initial query like this: 
context.Loans

SQL

```
SELECT 
    [LoanNumber] AS [LoanNumber], 
    [SEC_OWNER] AS [SEC_OWNER]
FROM [dbo].[Loans]
```

should be modified to following:

```
SELECT 
    O.LoanNumber AS LoanNumber, 
    O.SEC_OWNER AS SEC_OWNER, 
FROM   dbo.Loans AS O
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Users U
    ON 
        O.SEC_OWNER = U.SEC_ID 
        AND
        U.Name = N'root'
WHERE 
        ((256 = (O.SEC_PERMISSIONS & 256)) 
        AND 
        (O.SEC_OWNER = U.SEC_ID))


var joinExpression = expression.LeftOuterJoin(
                userEntityBase.Scan(),
                (l, r) =>
                    l.Property("SEC_OWNER").Equal(r.Property("SEC_ID"))
                    .And(r.Property("Name").Equal(DbExpression.FromString(this.UserName)))
                )
                .Where(
                    exp =>
                        DbExpressionBuilder
                            .Constant((int)AccessPermissions.OwnerRead).Equal(exp.Property("l").Property("SEC_PERMISSIONS").BitwiseAnd(DbExpressionBuilder.Constant((int)AccessPermissions.OwnerRead)))
                            .And(exp.Property("l").Property("SEC_OWNER").Equal(exp.Property("r").Property("SEC_ID")))
            );
```

As I understand join projects columns from both table. But I need to project only initial select without knowing it.

```
SELECT 
    [LoanNumber] AS [LoanNumber], 
    [SEC_OWNER] AS [SEC_OWNER]
```

Thanks in advance,

/Artem

Answer (score 0):

As a work around to that issue we removed JOIN from the query and decided to use subselects.

```
public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression) {
```

...

```
                var userEntityBase = expression.Target.EntityContainer.GetEntitySetByName("User", true);

                var newExpression = expression
                    .Where(
                        exp =>
                            ...
                                .And(exp.Property("SEC_OWNER")
                                    .Equal(userEntityBase.Scan().Where(user => user.Property("NAME").Equal(DbExpression.FromString(UserName))).Select(u => u.Property("SEC_ID")).Take(1).Element())
                                )
                            )
                            ...
                );

                ...

            return base.Visit(expression);
        }
```

.Select(u => u.Property("SEC_ID")).Take(1).Element() evaluates to SELECT TOP 1